# Replace Ethernet authentication credentials in Powershell

Tags: windows-10, networking, powershell, authentication

I have a situation where I need to use multiple IP in order to access some resources. In order to that I have to change my IP address every time by going to *Network Connection*, selecting *Ethernet* -> *Properties* -> *Authentication* -> *Additional Setting* -> *Replace Credentials* in the Advanced setting dialog and changing my credentials by using a different username and password and then I get assigned a different IP address.
Is there a way to do that in CMD or PowerShell,`Get-NetConnectionProfile` is telling me that I am *DomainAuthenticated* but I have no way of changing my Username and Password.

Comment: Are you connected to an AD domain?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I am.

Comment: I’m not familiar with 802.1x. It appears you can set it up using `netsh`, specifically the `netsh lan` namespace and in there, the `netsh lan set eapuserdata` operation.

Comment: @DanielB `set eapuserdata filename="UserData.xml"` it needs UserData.xml as a required parameter.

Comment: Yeah, sure. You just need to find out how to create this XML file. ;-) (Or whether this is the correct operation at all.)

Comment: It looks like the XML file cannot contain the credentials, but they are instead saved to the registry here `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wlansvc\UserData\Profiles\{GUID}\MSMUserData` See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15565093/7411885